# How to use date picker instead of textfield?

Tags: ios, xcode, soap, datepicker, uitextfield

I have 2 textfields and 1 button. I used textfield for entered date but I must use date picker.

This code for entering date to textfield and display some fields to labels.How I change for date picker this code?

ViewController.h

```
  @interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>

 - (IBAction)Send:(UIButton *)sender;
 @property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Date1;
 @property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Date2;
 //will here define for date picker
 @end
```

ViewController.m

```
 @interface ViewController (){
 NSMutableData *webData;
NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
NSMutableString *returnSOAP;
BOOL tReturn;


  }
 @end
 @implementation ViewController
 @synthesize Date1,Date2;

- (IBAction)Send:(UIButton *)sender{

    NSString *msgSOAP= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" 
     encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                   "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   
            instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
             xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                   "<soap:Body>\n"
                   "<ShowDetails xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                   "<date1>%@</date1>\n"
                   "<date2>%@</date2>\n"

                   "</ShowDetails>\n"
                   "</soap:Body>\n"
                   "</soap:Envelope>\n",Date1.text,Date2.text];


  NSLog(@"SOAP Resulr = \n%@\n\n", msgSOAP);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice/service.asmx"];

     NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];       
     NSString *dnMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [msgSOAP length]];

 [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/ShowDetails" 
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest dnMsg forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[msgSOAP dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest  
delegate:self];

if(con){
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Connection Error.");
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the format that you want to your date? You need to use the inputView and inputAccessoryView of textField to display a datePicker. Select a date, convert it using a dateFormatter and set it as text of textField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting you correct you want use datePicker so that user enter correct date and you don't have to validate the entered date.

You can use the inputView of textField. Use an inputAccessoryView to dispaly another view where you can put some buttons to dismiss the inputView.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIDatePicker *_datePicker;
    UIToolbar *_pickerToolBar;

    UITextField *_activeTextField;

    NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)addInputViewToTextField:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (!_datePicker) {
        _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        [_datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    }

    textField.inputView = _datePicker;

    if (!_pickerToolBar) {
        _pickerToolBar =[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,44)];
        _pickerToolBar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                     target:self
                                                                                     action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                     target:self
                                                                                     action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                   target:self
                                                                                   action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
        [_pickerToolBar setItems:@[cancelButton,flexibleSpace, doneButton]];
    }


    textField.inputAccessoryView = _pickerToolBar;

}

- (void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{

    if (!_dateFormatter) {
        _dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    }

    _activeTextField.text = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date];
    [_activeTextField resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    [_activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    _activeTextField = textField;
    [self addInputViewToTextField:textField];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    _activeTextField = nil;
}
```

[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestDateTextField.zip)

Comment: This is great example for me thank you.Thank you.How can I change date format like 21.11.2012

Comment: @MehmetAkyel Good to know that you find it useful. I didn't know your dateFormat so i used a generic one. `[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"]`, instead of dateStyle and timeStyle. And don't forget to accept ;)

Comment: I entered date field for calling from web servis.In web servis calling field has 21.12.2012 date format

Comment: @MehmetAkyel I have updated my answer, is it not working now?

Comment: It is work very nice.Thank you so much.I have a question to you.I have 3 textfield.Station ID,Date1,Date2 textfileds.I want to use this code for only 2 textfiled.Is this code for all of textfields on form ?

Comment: @MehmetAkyel Give each textField a tag, say 1, 2, 3 respectively. In the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method call the inputView method only if it 2 or 3. As simple as that.

Comment: How can I clear selected date in textfiled with my clear button and convert selected date to string for send to web service .This code for sending web service but it is not working -(IBAction) send:(UIButton *) sender { NSString *msgSOAP =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version...............",DateTextField.text ];}      This code for clean but it is not working -(IBAction) clear :(UIButton *) sender { DateTextField.text=@"",}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29721/discussion-between-anupdas-and-mehmet-akyel)

Answer (score 0):

USe this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
{  
   //Check the textfield for which you want to display date picker
    if(textField == datePickerTextField)
    {
       [self showDatePicker];
       return NO; //to disallow editing i.e it will not open keyboard
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I think you did not understand my question